# Accessing SOQL results

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, compile-error

How do I access the fields coming from the `Parent_Project_if_applicable__r` Relationship?  Syntax assistance.

```
List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name,Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c,
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.PM_Implementation_Status__c, 
                                                Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.RCM_Implementation_Status__c    
                                       FROM Case
                                       WHERE AccountId IN :AcctIds];

            System.debug('This is CaseList ' + caseList);

            for(Case cl:caseList){ 

               // System.debug('Implementation Status: ' + (String)cl.get('Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c'));
               // System.debug('cl: '+ cl);

            }
```

Comment: n.b. traversing relationships is covered in the [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql) module on Trailhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cl` represents each case in the iteration. You need to get it the same way you query for the data including parent record fields in SOQL statement.

```
for(Case cl:caseList){ 
        System.debug('Implementation Status: ' + cl.Parent_Project_if_applicable__r.Implementation_status__c);
    }
```